# Testing a create action with rspec and factory is failing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, factory-bot

I'm trying to test a post/create controller action in my rails 4 app, but it's failing.

Here is the scaffold generated test:

```
it "assigns a newly created project as @project" do
  post :create, {:project => valid_attributes}, valid_session
  assigns(:project).should be_a(Project)
  assigns(:project).should 
end
```

Here is the code after I refactored to use it with FactoryGirl

```
  it "assigns a newly created project as @project" do
    project = FactoryGirl.create(:post)
    assigns(project).should be_a(Project)
    assigns(project).should be_persisted
  end
```

So it's failing:

```
 Failure/Error: assigns(project).should be_a(Project)
   expected nil to be a kind of Project(id: integer, title: string, description: text, created_at: datetime, updated_at: datetime)
```

I don't know why `project`is returning `nil` in assigns method. I already inspected it to make sure it's returning a proper Project.

Btw, here is my project factory:

```
factory :project do
  title "MyString"
  description "MyText"
  users {[FactoryGirl.create(:user)]}
end
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `assigns(project)` method call returns the value of the `@project` instance variable in Rails. Invoking the FactoryGirl method has no effect on this variable, so it evaluates to `nil`.

Comment: So I'm supposed to extract my factory's attributes to use in `valid_attributes`?

Comment: Sort of. You don't need to create an instance and then "extract" them, you can just call `FactoryGirl.attributes_for(..).` I just noticed, though, that in your attempt to use `FactoryGirl` you passed in `:post`. Did you mean to do that rather than passing in `:project`?  I would think you'd want `post :create, {:project => FactoryGirl.attributes_for(:project)}, valid_session`